# Flex 4 scroller with group. Scrollbars not showing up

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, scroller

I know I have done this before but every time I work with scrollers and group it doesn't work for me and kills my 2 days.

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollPolicy="auto">
    <s:Group clipAndEnableScrolling="true">...... ..... </s:Group></s:Scroller>
```

This is what I have. I have components inside my group with is more than enough to bring scrollers even on a big monitor. But I am not getting any scrollbars.

Kindly tell me what is that I am doing wrong here. because everytime I fix it and I struggle for the next time.

Thanks.

Comment: remove clipAndEnableScrolling and it should work as expected

Comment: Hi, I just tried it and still not working :( is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: set your scroller width and height to like 300.  then try.  Got Scrollbars?  if so, then you are not reaching container width and height.  Scroller width="100%" says it will keep stretching till it hits the bounds of its parent container.

Answer (score 5):

Try with this

Your scroller parent container need to set non-percentage height/width.

```
<s:BorderContainer width="120" height="100" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Group>
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify"
                                  clipAndEnableScrolling="true" />
            </s:layout>
            <s:Button label="button (1)" />
            <s:Button label="button (2)" />
            <s:Button label="button (3)" />
            <s:Button label="button (4)" />
            <s:Button label="button (5)" />
            <s:Button label="button (6)" />
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: The above code worked but I wanted to have the scrollers at the edges to make it look like browser's scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for all your responses. After setting the minHeight it now works. I am able to achieve the scrollbars as expected (make it look like browser's scroll bar). Below is the code snippet

`<s:Scroller width="100%" maxHeight="{this.height}">
    <s:VGroup width="100%" minHeight="1000" height="100%" paddingLeft="40" paddingRight="40" paddingTop="0" >
..</s:VGroup></s:Scroller>`

Kindly let me know if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

The Same code given by "Raja Jaganathan" itself will work with small modification on scroll parent height and width

Capabilities.screenResolutionX, Capabilities.screenResolutionY  will give you the browser width and height respectively.